# Excel VBA create a date+time value

Tags: vba, excel, date

In my table I have two columns containing data of type: `yyyymmdd` and `hhmmddxx` - first contains date and the other time with precision to 0.01 seconds. So for example I have `20161102` and `17052349`.

I want to convert this into a single value showing a moment in time and display this in format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.xx`, so for example I want to get `02/11/2016 17:05:23.49`. I think I need to use `DateSerial` and `TimeSerial` functions, but there are two problems I have no idea how to go around:

1. TimeSerial accepts hour, minute and second as argument, all are Integer type, how to pass fractions of a second to it?
2. DateSerial will create my day and TimeSerial will create my time, is there a function that takes date and time as argument and creates a single "that day, on that time" value out of this?

Comment: There isn't, but you could use what you have for date, then timeserial on mid of sections of 2, for timeserial, and add, and have a custom string o/p so in essence, your own function GENERATE_TIMESTAMP() as string maybe

Comment: as to number 2, add them together to get the date and time DateSerial() + TimeSerial() = specific date time.  Date is a long and time a decimal so the two together = a double.

Comment: Dates and times are held as numbers. They are only displayed as dates and or times because of NumberFormat. Dates are held as days since 1/1/1900. Times are held as SecondsSinceMidnight / SecondsInDay. So Dates are whole numbers. Times are fractions. They can be added.

Comment: No Excel or VBA function of which I am aware displays fractions of a seconds correctly although values are held to the nearest 1/1000th of a second.  I have code for this somewhere.  I will look but no promises.  If I remember correctly, my code multiples the fraction of a second by SecondsInDay * 100 and then left pads that value with a zero to get the fraction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this, maybe??

`? generate_timestamp("20161102","170522349")`

gives

`02/11/2016 17:05:23.49`

```
Function GENERATE_TIMESTAMP(strDate As String, strTime As String) As String

Dim dtDate As Date
Dim dtTime As Date

dtDate = DateSerial(Mid(strDate, 1, 4), Mid(strDate, 5, 2), Mid(strDate, 8, 2))
dtTime = TimeSerial(Mid(strTime, 1, 2), Mid(strTime, 3, 2), Mid(strTime, 6, 2))

GENERATE_TIMESTAMP = FormatDateTime(dtDate, vbShortDate) & " " & _
                        FormatDateTime(dtTime, vbLongTime) & "." & _
                        Mid(strTime, 8, 2)

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: After testing found formatting was dropping the fractions of seconds, and just repeating fractions. I devised this formula to resolve. Note that the formula here does not output a serial representation of the datetime but is just a text string.

```
=TEXT(DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2))+TIME(LEFT(B1,2),MID(B1,3,2),MID(B1,5,2)),"m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss")&"."&RIGHT(B1,2)
```

PREVIOUS RESPONSE:

You can create the serial using the following formula:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2))+TIME(LEFT(B1,2),MID(B1,3,2),MID(B1,5,2))+(RIGHT(B1,2)/(24*60*60*100))
```

And then format your cell as Custom with m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss.ss. Here I am not passing the fraction of seconds to the `TIME()` function but rather adding as a fraction of a day.

Comment: Actually testing further I see an error in that custom formatting will only show the integer seconds. So in your example for seconds it would show "23.23" rather than "23.49". Thinking about alternate solution. Apologies.